# How can i check two angles if they are the same using radians

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

What i am trying to do is check if two Nodes(objects) are pointing in the same direction. But the problem is that SpriteKit rotates nodes in radians so it keeps adding to the zRotation of the node.

what i do for the rotation is:

```
if(touched_location.x >= self.frame.size.width/2)
{       
   node1.runAction(SKaction.RotateByAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI_2), 1.0)
}
else if(touched_location.x <= self.frame.size.width/2)
{
   node1.runAction(SKAction.RotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_2), 1.0)
}
```

so this rotates the node for 90° but RotateByAngle uses radians which is fine it sill works.

But radians keep adding to zRotation so i end up with something like 12,45 radians (not accurate number just for refrence) and this does not match the radians of my second Node(node2) that i am comparing the zRotation to.

For checking the rotation im using:

```
var first = CGFloat(round(100*node1.zRotation)/100)
var second = CGFloat(round(100*node2.zRoation)/100)
if(first == second)
{
    do stuff....
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work cause if you keep rotation node in one direction the radian is to high (or to low if other direction) but visually the direction is the same.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the whole circle (360 deg) has angle 2 * PI, so 0 and 2 * PI represents the same 'normalized' angle.

```
import Foundation

func normalizeDifferenceAngleInRadians(a1: Double, _ a2: Double)->Double {
    let twoPi = 2 * M_PI
    return (a2 - a1) % twoPi
}

let a1 = M_PI_2
let a2 = 5 * M_PI_2
let diff = normalizeDifferenceAngleInRadians(a1, a2) // 0
```

based on Martin's note

```
import Foundation

func angleDifferenceInRadians(a1: Double, _ a2: Double)->Double {
    let twoPi = 2 * M_PI
    return -((a2 - a1 + M_PI) % twoPi - M_PI)
}

let a1 = M_PI_2
let a2 = 5 * M_PI_2 + 0.001
let a3 = 5 * M_PI_2 - 0.001
let diff1 = angleDifferenceInRadians(a1, a2) // -0.001
let diff2 = angleDifferenceInRadians(a1, a3) //  0.001
```

@0x141E thank you! I hope, the code below will be the final and correct implementation of my 'new year mathematical exercise'. Sometimes the simple trouble and quick correction leads to bigger trouble ...

```
func angleDifferenceInRadians(a1: Double, _ a2: Double)->Double {
    let twoPi = 2 * M_PI
    let d = (a2 - a1) % twoPi
    let s = d < 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0
    return d * s < M_PI ? d : (d - s * twoPi)
}
```

Comment: Note that for a1=0.0, a2=2*M_PI-0.001, the result is a value close to 2π, so in order to detect "almost equal angles" and because of rounding errors, you'll want to normalize the value to be in the range -π ... π

Comment: @MartinR yes, that is probably good idea to do, I agree. Thanks!

Comment: Now `angleDifferenceInRadians(a2, a1)` gives a large negative value :)

Comment: @MartinR positive vs negative === clockwise vs counterclockwise.

Comment: Sure, but if you want to check if two angles point (approximately) into the same direction, then the order should not matter.

Comment: @MartinR :-) depends on definition, but i will make another 'update'! because generally, you are right!

Comment: ok im gona be honest here i have no idea what this does :| what are a1 and a2. What i understanded from this was a1 = node1, a2 = node2 then put this two in the AngleDifferenceInRadians function and if it returns 0 then they are the same angle. Is that correct or am i just stupid??

Comment: @KlemenAndrašič a1 is the first angle (or direction, if you want) a2 is the second one. if the result is close to + or - 0, the directions are approximately the same. if the result is close to + or - M_PI (PI radians), that means approximately the opposite direction

Comment: @user3441734 ah ok i see thank you for clarifing that up :)

Comment: @KlemenAndrašič thanks should go to Martin as well. Enjoy it! Happy New Year and happy coding!

Comment: Neither approach handles angles near pi and 2*pi correctly. For example, if a1 = M_PI-0.001 and a2 = -M_PI+0.001. The difference should be 0.002 but both functions return about + or - 2*pi.

Comment: @0x141E  that is because M_PI and -M_PI means the OPPOSITE directions! the result is correct.

Comment: @user3441734 0 and pi are opposite directions. -pi and pi are in the same direction.

Comment: @0x141E sorry! there are NOT OPOSITE directions, the result of the function is close to 0 and NOT close to 2PI  'let a1 = M_PI + 0.001
let a2 = M_PI - 0.001
let diff1 = angleDifferenceInRadians(a1, a2) //  0.0019999'

Comment: @user3441734 try `a1 = M_PI-0.001` and `a2 = -M_PI+0.001` (my example in the above comment).

Comment: @0x141E after few drinks (happy new year!) and without my glasses, it will be better if i will correct it tomorrow :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99437/discussion-between-user3441734-and-0x141e).